# ASP.NET Repeater header and column width

Tags: repeater, itemtemplate

I have a repeater control, with HeaderTemplate and ItemTemplate both having tables -- The header has 4 column names with a th tag, and the ItemTemplate is being databaound.

The issue is that itemtemplate column do not align properly with the header column names -- Is there a way to align them without explicitly supplying td column widths -- Fixed td widths, I think, may not expand when the containing page expands.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I figured out, one table inside the templates did the trick.